# Get The iframe attribute data from inside of the iframe

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, iframe

I was wondering if it's possible to get an iframe attribute from inside that Iframe using Javascript.

For example, let's say I have:

```html
<iframe src"google.com" class="myClass" id="myId"></iframe>
```

If I wanted to grab the value of the `class` attribute (MyClass) from inside the iframe, how could I do it?

I tried `window.class` & `window.className`.

PS: If this question has been asked before I apologize, I've looked and I was not able to find one that answers it.

Comment: Is frame src on same domain/origin as page frame is in? If so you need to traverse to top window and look in that document. If different origins then browser security policies will block you

Comment: in the above example you are running the code from google.com. or you asking how to get myclass from js that is in a script alongside the iframe

Answer (score 0):

you cannot get the values of attributes with window.className.

Instead use this...

```
const iframe = document.getElementById("myId");

iframe.getAttribute("class"); //<-you can select any attribute with this method
    //or
console.log(iframe.classList)
```